# Logarithmic non-linear system of equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, mathematical-physics, nonlinear-system

As part of an heat exchanger problem, we are given two unknowns $T_{cs}$ and $T_{fs}$ solving the following equations: $\forall (Q,U,F, m_c,m_f, C_c,C_f, \Sigma , T_{ce},T_{fe}) \in \mathbb{R_+^*}^{10}, Q = U \Sigma F \frac{T_{ce}-T_{fs} -T_{cs} +T_{fe}}{ln(\frac{T_{ce}-T_{fe}}{T_{cs}-T_{fs}})} = m_c \cdot C_c (T_{ce} - T_{cs}) = m_f C_f (T_{fs} - T_{fe})$

*Side note*: f means cold (froid in french), c means hot (chaud in french), s means outlet (sortie in french), e means inlet (entrée in french).

Then, I thought, oh that's easy, let's isolate the two variables and solve the system.

We introduce the change of variables:

- $x = T_{cs}$
- $y = T_{fs}$
- $A = \frac{m_c \cdot C_c}{U \Sigma F} \in \mathbb{R^*_+}$
- $B = \frac{m_f \cdot C_f}{U \Sigma F} \in \mathbb{R^*_+}$

We get the following system (two equations of two unknowns):

$\frac{T_{ce} - y - x + T_{fe}}{ln(\frac{T_{ce}-y}{x - T_{fe}})} = A (T_{ce} - x) = B(y-T_{fe})$

I introduce another change of variable so that it's more comfortable for math people (these are constants):

- $\Gamma = T_{ce}$
- $\Lambda = T_{fe}$

We get:

$$\frac{\Gamma + \Lambda - y - x}{ln(\frac{\Gamma-y}{x - \Lambda})} = A (\Gamma - x) = B(y-\Lambda)$$

\begin{cases} \frac{\Gamma + \Lambda - y - x}{ln(\frac{\Gamma-y}{x - \Lambda})} = A (\Gamma - x) \\ \frac{\Gamma + \Lambda - y - x}{ln(\frac{\Gamma-y}{x - \Lambda})} = B (y - \Lambda) \end{cases}

Therefore my question is: $\forall (A,B,\Lambda, \Gamma) \in \mathbb{R_+^*}^4,$ solve:
\begin{cases} \frac{\Gamma + \Lambda - y - x}{ln(\frac{\Gamma-y}{x - \Lambda})} = A (\Gamma - x) \\ \frac{\Gamma + \Lambda - y - x}{ln(\frac{\Gamma-y}{x - \Lambda})} = B (y - \Lambda) \end{cases}

My attempt was to find an exponential change of variable that would work but it didn't worked out well (in heat exchangers, the profile is an exponential). I also tried all the methods I knew for non-linear systems of equations without much results.

*Remark*: You might think that the coefficients are wrong because we have terms with the form $\Gamma - y$ inside the logarithm and $y - \Lambda$ in the RHS, and that I just messed up the index of my temperatures. Well the LHS corresponds to a [logarithmic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_mean_temperature_difference) between the temperature at the origin of space $x=0$ and the end of the exchanger $x=L$. Here, we have a [counter-flow exchanger](https://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node131.html#SECTION07452000000000000000), so the inlet of the hot fluid is the outlet of the cold fluid and vice-versa. While on the RHS, it corresponds to a change of enthalpy between $x=0$ and $x=L$.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{\Gamma + \Lambda - y - x}{\log(\frac{\Gamma-y}{x - \Lambda})} = A (\Gamma - x)\tag 1$$ $$\frac{\Gamma + \Lambda - y - x}{\log(\frac{\Gamma-y}{x - \Lambda})} = B (y - \Lambda) \tag 2$$

Since the lhs are the same
$$A (\Gamma - x)= B (y - \Lambda)\implies y=\frac{A (\Gamma -x)}{B}+\Lambda$$ Plug this values in $(1)$ to get
$$(x-\Gamma ) \left(\frac{\frac{A}{B}-1}{\log \left(\frac{-A \Gamma +A x+B \Gamma -B
   \Lambda }{B (x- \Lambda) }\right)}+A\right)=0$$ Excluding $x=\Gamma$, then
$$\color{blue}{x=\Lambda+\frac{e^{\frac{1}{B}} (A-B) (\Gamma -\Lambda )}{A e^{\frac{1}{B}}-B e^{\frac{1}{A}}}}$$
$$\color{blue}{y=\Gamma-\frac{e^{\frac{1}{A}} (A-B) (\Gamma -\Lambda )}{A e^{\frac{1}{B}}-B e^{\frac{1}{A}}}} $$

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't thought of combining the two RHS.

Comment: @PackSciences. You are welcome ! Notice that using $X=x-\Lambda$, $Y=\Gamma-y$ makes the problem simpler (in fact, it is what I did).